# Looking for a complete tutorial about ChronoConnectivity

Tags: joomla

I am trying to work with ChronoConnectivity and I have read all the tutorials available about it.
Still, I have'nt found any tutorial that talks about the "Custom Display Type" or the "hasMany" relationship between models. Would someone please help me find a complete tutorial about ChronoConnectivity?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=chronoconnectivity+tutorial

Comment: @Yoleth thank you so much for your link. I came to ask for a tutorial here because I didn't find any good one after searching on Google. The tutorials I found there only talk about the basics of chronoconnectivity. I need to know more about the "Custom Display Type" and the "hasMany" relationship between models. Thanks.